# logic symbols different from pc to mac

Tags: utf-8, logical-operators, discrete-mathematics

I'm taking an online Discrete Math course for computer science, and I've noticed in the forums that with special characters such as `negation: ¬` or `implication: →` do not show up correctly for me on a mac when written by a student with a PC.

Here's how they show up for me:[image: Screenshot of wrong symbols]

I tried inspecting the element to see if i could change the font or find a character code, but I just see the `registered trademark symbol: ®`

[image: web inspector]

I think students are copying symbols from the teacher's Microsoft office docs.  **Is there any workflow I could suggest to the whole class so we can all see the correct symbols?**  It's really screwing me up.  I can see symbols from other mac users, I can see the symbols on wikipedia, and no one has complained about not being able to see my symbols.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question?

Comment: Can you suggest somewhere to ask this?

Comment: Possibly http://superuser.com